# User Control Inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a UserControl inside a repeater. The repeater's datasource is from SQL Server.

User Control's .cs - MoviePanel.ascx.cs:

---

```
public int myMovieID { get; set; }
public string myMovieName { get; set; }
public string myMovieDescription { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MovieIDLbl.Text = myMovieID.ToString();
   MovieNameLbl.Text = myMovieName;
   DescriptionLbl.Text = myMovieDescription;
}
```

ASPX Page:

---

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" DataSourceID="ListOfMoviesDS" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:MovieDetailPanel runat="server" myMovieID='<%# Eval("MovieID") %>' 
           myMovieName='<%# Eval("movieName") %>' 
                myMovieDescription='<%# Eval("movieDescription") %>' 
                id="MovieDetailPanel1" />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("MovieID") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Eval("movieName") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Eval("movieDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here something very strange happens. The values are not getting passed to the UserControl. However, if I place Labels below the usercontrol and set text with `Eval()` it works. You might think the usercontrol might be the problem. But if I manually type something, say in place of `<%# Eval("movieName") %>` it gets passed to the user control and gets displayed.

I have NO CLUE! If the problem is with Eval() Labels should not get the text as well. Or if the problem is with the UserControl my manual text shouldn't get passed. I have no idea why Eval()'s values is not reaching the UserControl.

Comment: Could you please let me know how I'm supposed to pass values to the UserControl from code behind ? I can assign the data source of the repeater but how are values from the datasource passed to the usercontrol ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle are you checking to see if the values are set? You are using data binding expressions, so those will be set during the `DataBinding` phase.

Comment: I am checking on the PageLoad event of the UserControl(as shown in the example above). Is that wrong ?

Comment: Your question makes sense to me. Can you let me know how am I supposed to hold off the control until the values are set/bound ? I mean, is there an event function that I can add to get the values instead of doing it from Page_Load() ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Your code is working fine; I tested it (see the bottom of the page).** The worst case you can try assigning those value inside ItemDataBound event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:MoviePanel runat="server" id="MovieDetailPanel1" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie {MovieID = 1, MovieName = "One", MovieDescription = "One hundred"},
            new Movie {MovieID = 2, MovieName = "Two", MovieDescription = "Two hundreds"},
            new Movie {MovieID= 3, MovieName = "Three", MovieDescription = "Three hundreds"},
        };
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var movie = e.Item.DataItem as Movie;

        var control = e.Item.FindControl("MovieDetailPanel1") as MoviePanel;
        control.myMovieID = movie.MovieID;
        control.myMovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription;
        control.myMovieName = movie.MovieName;
    }
}
```

[image]

## Here is how I test your original question

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebDemo.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register src="MoviePanel.ascx" tagname="MoviePanel" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:MoviePanel runat="server" mymovieid='<% #Eval("MovieID") %>'
                    mymoviename='<% #Eval("movieName") %>'
                    mymoviedescription='<% #Eval("movieDescription") %>'
                    id="MovieDetailPanel1" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


namespace WebDemo
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Movie
        {
            public int MovieID { get; set; }
            public string MovieName { get; set; }
            public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Movie>
                {
                    new Movie {MovieID = 1, MovieName = "One", MovieDescription = "One hundred"},
                    new Movie {MovieID = 2, MovieName = "Two", MovieDescription = "Two hundreds"},
                    new Movie {MovieID= 3, MovieName = "Three", MovieDescription = "Three hundreds"},
                };
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="MoviePanel.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebDemo.MoviePanel" %>

<p>
    <strong>Inside Control</strong>:
    <asp:Label ID="MovieIDLbl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="MovieNameLbl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLbl" runat="server" />
</p>

namespace WebDemo
{
    public partial class MoviePanel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public int myMovieID { get; set; }
        public string myMovieName { get; set; }
        public string myMovieDescription { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MovieIDLbl.Text = myMovieID.ToString();
            MovieNameLbl.Text = myMovieName;
            DescriptionLbl.Text = myMovieDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you use Binding on the User Control? Here you are using Binding on the Repeater, but then NOT using Binding on the User Control. Instead, this code is manually setting the Text property. This just doesn't make sense. What is the point of using User Controls if they can't use Binding?

Comment: @Rhyous It might be that OP wants to separate some business logic with other controls.

Answer (score 4):

here is one way, doing it all in the code behind.  I can't say this is best practice, but it's clean.  You use the ItemDataBind event, cast the item to what you want, datatable, whatever, then create a new instance of the user control and add it to the repeater's control collection

**Page source**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        myRepeater.DataSource = myList;
        myRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    public void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = (string)e.Item.DataItem;
        var newcontrol = (WebUserControl1)Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
        newcontrol.myTest = items;
        myRepeater.Controls.Add(newcontrol);           
    }   
}
```

**Page html**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater"  runat="server" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**user control**

```
<h1 id="myLabel" runat="server"></h1>
```

and

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string myTest { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.InnerText = myTest;
    }
}
```