# Is it possible to pass object as parameters in a web user control markup?

Tags: webforms, aspx-user-control

I am building a web page that lists products, using aspx webform. For that, in a user control corresponding to my list, I am looping over my products and injecting one new user control by product:

```
        foreach (Product p in this.Products)
        {
            ucProductItem.product = p;
    %>
    <uc:ucProductItem runat="server" ID="ucProductItem" />
    <%
        }
    %>
```

This works fine and I am OK with that... BUT not totally because I find this quite ugly and messy; I don't like the mixing of markup and code in the template, and I try to use markup as much as possible (and I have this problem all over my project).

Thus, I would like to pass the product `p` to the new `ucProductItem` user control via the markup, and I tried naturaly something like:

```
<uc:ucProductItem runat="server" ID="ucProductItem" product=p />
```

I know this is possible for primitive types such as strings and integers, but I can not figure out how to do it with objects.

Is that possible ? And how ?

Comment: Premise: you are using webforms in not standard way. In webforms you can create ascx (or directly in the page) containing a GridView.
In your case, you can add a public Property Product UCProduct in your UcProductItem and assign it in DataBound event of your container control. I need to see more code for more help: how the Product property will be used?

Comment: Hi Emanuele, I was not aware of the GridView stuff (yes, i am a newbie in webforms) and I am heading straight to check that. The Product propertie will be used to display a "card" with a brief description of the product (like in all commercial sites on the web).

Comment: I suggest to read about GridView (if you need pagination) or Repeater control.

Comment: Question already asked and resolved !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136479/user-control-inside-repeater